# How do you add a unique constraint on multiple navigation properties in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, indexing

I have the following entity, which gives me an auto-incremented PK, two columns (or in EF jargon "Relationships") and a boolean value. It works as expected.

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SomeID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserAttribute UserAttribute { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; } 
}
```

Now I want to add a constraint so that combinations `UserAttribute` and `User` have to be unique. This is in lieu of making them a composite primary key. So I add some annotations and it looks like this:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SomeID { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_MyTwoColumns", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual UserAttribute UserAttribute { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_MyTwoColumns", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; } 
}
```

When I look at the indexes in Management Studio, I don't see `IX_MyTwoColumns`. Suspecting that this had something to do with using a relationship, I added two dummy columns, `foo` and `bar` and specified a unique multi-column index:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SomeID { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_MyTwoColumns", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual UserAttribute UserAttribute { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_MyTwoColumns", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_FooAndBar", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_FooAndBar", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public bool Value { get; set; } 
}
```

And `IX_FooAndBar` appears in the designer and indeed shows those two columns are part of the unique index.

What am I doing wrong? It appears I'm setting up the FK for `User` and `UserAttribute`, but I've no idea on how to ensure their combination will be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data annotation you need to insert indexes on the columns of the relation.

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SomeID { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_MyTwoColumns", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int UserAttributeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserAttributeId")]
    public virtual UserAttribute UserAttribute { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_MyTwoColumns", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Is that some sort of EF behind the scenes magic?  How does EF know that those ID columns belong to the Reltionship?  I suppose it wouldn't work if both of those tables used "ID" instead of XXXID?

Comment: :) In this case is the ForeignKeyAttribute before the navigation property. On UserId property you can also use the Column attribute.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I tried added UserID and and UserAttributeID before you responded and it worked!  Though I did not include the [ForeignKey("XXX")] annotation.  The ER diagram and indexes appear to be the same.  Is this annotation really necessary?  I hate it when something works and I suspect it should not!

Comment: After some experimentation I discovered it is NOT necessary, but if you want CASCADE DELETE to work (and not have to use fluent in OnModelCreating) it is required.  Does that sound right?  If so you just killed two birds with one stone!

Comment: am i correct about the cascading when using ForeignKey?  Getting some pressure from the bosses to finish this up.  :)